# How do i transform a HQL result to List<T> where T is a mapped class

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hql

I have this nhibernate query:

```
var q =
               NHibernateSession.Current.CreateSQLQuery
               (
                    @"SELECT  LastestEvents.*
                    FROM    (
                            SELECT  DISTINCT SbQcontainer.Container
                            FROM    HistoricEvents
                            SbQcontainer WHERE SbQcontainer.LineCompany_Id = :lineCompany) as Sbq
                             JOIN HistoricEvents as  LastestEvents
                    ON      LastestEvents.id = (
                            SELECT TOP(1) id
                            FROM    HistoricEvents mi
                            WHERE   mi.Container = Sbq.Container and mi.LineCompany_Id = :lineCompany
                            ORDER BY mi.Date DESC
                            )"
               ).SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(HistoricEvent)));

            q.SetParameter("lineCompany",lineCompany.Id);
            q.SetCacheable(false);

            var results = q.List<HistoricEvent>().ToList();
```

It looks for the lastest events on each container for the given lineCompany, it works, but i dont know how to set this resultset to a list of  T HistoricEvent, i try this line:

```
.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(HistoricEvent)));
```

But throws  NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException:Could not find a setter for property 'Event_Id' in class 'HistoricEvent'.

Is there any way to do this?, or maybe doing this same query using the ICriteria API?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming HistoricEvent is a mapped entity, the following should give you what you're looking for:

```
var q = 
               NHibernateSession.Current.CreateSQLQuery 
               ( 
                    @"SELECT  LastestEvents.* 
                    FROM    ( 
                            SELECT  DISTINCT SbQcontainer.Container 
                            FROM    HistoricEvents 
                            SbQcontainer WHERE SbQcontainer.LineCompany_Id = :lineCompany) as Sbq 
                             JOIN HistoricEvents as  LastestEvents 
                    ON      LastestEvents.id = ( 
                            SELECT TOP(1) id 
                            FROM    HistoricEvents mi 
                            WHERE   mi.Container = Sbq.Container and mi.LineCompany_Id = :lineCompany 
                            ORDER BY mi.Date DESC 
                            )" 
               ).AddEntity(typeof(HistoricEvent)); 

            q.SetParameter("lineCompany",lineCompany.Id); 
            q.SetCacheable(false); 

            var results = q.List<HistoricEvent>().ToList();
```

See the [relevant documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#d0e9908) for further details.